# jsPDF working on first save, not updating on second

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf, data-uri

Scenario: the user picks a few choices, downloads a PDF. The user then changes a few choices, and downloads a new PDF.

Problem: everything works on the first run, but attempting to download a second PDF gives the user the same, old PDF.

My idea/guess: the function that runs the jsPDF actions (make doc, adding content, save doc) are called on click. My assumption would be that ALL actions get run anew on click, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there some way to "clear" or "kill" the old PDF? I tried setting the var doc to null before running the function again, and that didn't help. Somehow the first PDF being generated is all I'm able to serve.

Here is the code that makes the PDF. Those frontImg and backImg vars contain the dataURI.

```
$(".button").click(function(){

  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

  doc.addImage(frontImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.addPage('a6','l');
  doc.addImage(backImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
  doc.save('file.pdf');

});
```

Anyone have any ideas here? Once the user takes actions that update the frontImg and backImg vars, shouldn't the PDF update too?

Comment: Hi, are you able to solve this issue? As I am facing the same issue too. Would appreciate it if you could update the answer :D

Answer (score 6):

try to initialise the doc once again...

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

    doc.addImage(frontImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
    doc.addPage('a6','l');
    doc.addImage(backImg, 'PNG', 0, 0, 300, 210);
    doc.save('file.pdf');
    doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
});
```

Comment: This isn't very efficient when using custom fonts, because you'd have to load the custom font file each time you initialize the document again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that the pdf was not updated when changing variables. Be careful and check if you are updating variables before creating a new pdf . on click you always create a new pdf .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31739001)